# How can I search among my own questions and answers?

Tags: support, search

As per the title, how can I search *only* among my questions and answers?

I'd want to do this because I consider my questions and answers my own personal knowledge base and I'd like to be able to constrain the search within that.

Comment: I'm actually shocked this isn't in the FAQ, or at least, I don't see an entry on searching your own entries in the FAQ.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas That's fine. I think it will be more useful, if there is a tool to allow searching among the questions I favorite too. or making it a separate search option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guess what - the feature exists.

In the search box, put `user:me` and any results will be limited to yourself.

See on the [search tips page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search), in the "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options" section.

Comment: Wow! wonderful, but does it extended to the favorites questions?

Comment: @sємsєм - That, I believe it doesn't.

Comment: @sємsєм favorites are in your profile.

Comment: I'm talking about search features, not only listing. Suppose, I need a snippet of code regarded in question I asked or I answered which it is meant by "arrays of teams" I want to be able to search and get only the results found in my questions and answers.

Comment: @amanaP All of your questions and answers are in your profile as well.

Comment: @jadarnel27 baah.

Comment: @Oded I tried [user:sємsєм] array and [user:me] array but there is no results (in my stackoverflow account)

Comment: @sємsєм - Sorry - the `[]` are not needed!